# Compare current status with previous months in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

In my table I have 2 columns date (containing month name - I converted it to date field) & Status (Text value which I converted to numeric). Status column which contains text value Green, Amber, Red and I converted it to Green = 1, Amber = 2, Red = 3. Now I want to compare status current month status with previous period.

```
Col.1    Col.2
1        01/01/2018
2        01/02/2018
3        01/06/2018
2        01/02/2018
3        01/03/2018
1        01/04/2018
```

As status change from green to amber it "down", green to red "down", amber to green "up', red to green"up". If last month & current month status same green to green than same or "blank".

```
if (Col.1=Col.1,"blank",if (Col.1>Col.1,"up",if (Col.1<col.1,"down")
```

I am trying to add 2 slicer which shows current status after comparing current month & previous month. e.g current month May and previous month February.

Is there any way I can get the desired results. In short one column contains values & other date and I want to return values in third column after comparing current month (could be any month) with previous month(could be any month).

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a table called 'status_table' and it has the values as mentioned below : 
[Table Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUZVF.jpg)

1. Create a new column with below DAX

   Row ID = RANKX(status_table,status_table[date],,ASC,Dense)

   [Row ID Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixXlo.jpg)
2. Create a new column with below DAX

   Previous Status = LOOKUPVALUE(status_table[status],status_table[Row ID],status_table[Row ID]-1)
   [Previous Status Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKVrd.jpg)
3. Create the final column to get the change in status

   Change in Status = if(status_table[status]=status_table[Previous Status],"blank",if(status_table[status]>status_table[Previous Status],"Up","Down"))

   [Change in Status Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ZtQ.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to do it with PreviousMonth fn. But the issues is I wanted to add two slicer where I can pass the date or month. In this case it will only compare with previous row. 

Status_Values       Month
1                   July
2                   Aug
3                   Sep
2                   Oct
1                   Nov
3                   Dec

Though above provided solutions helped me to resolved another query. Thanks a ton.
I am new in Power Query & DAX so please bear with me. Thanks a lot!